# ¿Cómo cambiar los eventos al click del mouse?

Tags: javascript

***VEASE UN EJEMPLO EN  - | MACROS | - Luego cuando Juegas (BOTON PLAY),en la mecánica de juego por defecto dar 1 PUNTO en el juego se apreta cliqueando la letra 'w' pero cuando lo cambias en el INPUT 'feed' , por cualquier otra letra, con tan solo apretar UNA VEZ la letra selecionada, es como que apretases la letra 'W' varias veces***

---

Este código lo que hace es obtener una letra de un `input`, y al obtenerla funciona como un 'Macrokeyboard', pero como lo puedo hacer con el mouse? Sé que los eventos del mouse son 1, 2, 3, pero no se me ocurre.

Lo que quiero lograr es que al hacer click derecho o izquierdo, realiza todo lo dentro del `if`, osea funcionar como macro de las teclas que se especifican dentro de `if`.

Y lo que realiza mi código actual es Obtener una letra del input, luego lo transformo con charCodeAt,luego dentro del if se ejecuta un tipo de Macrokeys, presionando la tecla que se escribio en un principio dentro del input.

Ejemplo:

Escribes en el input la letra 'A', luego en el documento al presionar UNA VEZ la letra 'A', automaticamente se presionarán 6 veces rápidamente la tecla Keycode 32

```js
(function() {
  var amount = 6;
  var duration = 50; //ms
  var letra = "";

  var overwriting = function(evt) {
    var obtener1 = document.getElementById('allsplits').value;
    var sub = obtener1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

    if (sub == '') {
      var code1 = 90;
    } else {
      var code1 = sub.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    if (evt.keyCode === code1) { // KEY_Z
      for (var i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          window.onkeydown({
            keyCode: 32
          }); // USER SPLIT
          window.onkeyup({
            keyCode: 32
          });
        }, i * duration);
      }
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('keydown', overwriting);
})();
```

```css
#allsplits {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  width: 80%; 
  height: 25px; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 65%; 
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<input id="allsplits" placeholder="Macro splits(Macro de espacios)" type="text">
```

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer? simular un click?, o que te haga algo al hacer click

Comment: ya lo edité @G3l0 .

Comment: Buen día. ¿Quieres detectar eventos de mouse para hacer qué?

Comment: ¿El click se hará solo en la caja de texto o en el documento?

Comment: Al input le enviara un 1 o un 3 segun el click(ya que no veo otra forma) y luego en el documento cada vez que se presiona el click que se indico se autopresionan las teclas dentro del if mas rapido de lo normal

Comment: Deberías describir mejor qué es lo que hace el código que compartes. No termina de quedar muy claro qué es lo que hace o qué es lo que quieres que haga.

Comment: Ya lo actualizé, alvaro montoro

Comment: Ese código no ejecuta 6 veces el pulsado de la tecla. `onkeyup` y `onkeydown` son controladores de evento y no disparadores (_triggers_). Además, si ejecutas el código verás que recibes mensajes de error.

Comment: Pero se ejecuta como si la apretaras rapidamente

Comment: Puf no entiendo lo que dice. Llamar a las cosas por su nombre y sin lugar a dudas es lo mejor para formular una pregunta. Dice al hacer click al documento. se sobreentiende que la caja de texto no entra en ese evento usa los eventos de click
window.onclick

Comment: He agregado un ejemplo, porque soy bastante malo argumentando..

Comment: entonces lo que buscas es el atributo on click entiendo